# ggplot not using the colors specified in a column

Tags: r, ggplot2

When ploting this data frame:

```
   Country processing.level     yend        y col    
   <chr>              <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>  
 1 BRA                    1  957800        0  #073b4c
 2 BRA                    2  959258.  957800  #118ab2
 3 BRA                    3  538306.  959258. #06d6a0
 4 BRA                    4  301212.  538306. #ffd166
 5 BRA                    5  276294.  301212. #ef476f
 6 CHN                    1 1446265.       0  #073b4c
 7 CHN                    2 2234591. 1446265. #118ab2
 8 CHN                    3 2843813. 2234591. #06d6a0
 9 CHN                    4 2930715. 2843813. #ffd166
10 CHN                    5 1309941. 2930715. #ef476f
```

ggplot uses the colors specified in the `col` column, but not in the correct order. For example, `processing.level = 1`  is taking the color of `processing.level=2` and  `processing.level=3`is taking the color of `processing.level=1`.
My color is mapped inside aes of my ggplot, and the colors in the legend are getting ploted correctly. I cannot find the problem with the code of the plot.

```
consumption_supplychain %>%
  mutate(xval = as.numeric(factor(Country)) + scales::rescale(processing.level, to=c(-0.05, 0.05))) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_segment(aes(x = xval, xend = xval,y=y, yend = yend, color=consumption_supplychain$col),
               linejoin = 'bevel',
               lineend = 'butt',
               linewidth = 1.5,
               arrow = arrow(angle = 55, length = unit(1.5, "mm"))) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "",values = consumption_supplychain$col,
                     labels=c("Domestically produced hides",
                              "Trade in raw hides",
                              "Trade in tanned hides",
                              "Trade in leather",
                              "Trade in consumer goods"))+
  scale_x_continuous("", breaks = 1:5,
                     labels = c("Brazil", "China", "Eropean Union", "India", "USA")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_number(scale=1/1000000)) +
  #theme_light(base_size = 16)+
  ylab("Million tonnes per year")
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `scale_color_identity`

Comment: That worked but I had to manually specify the colors in the breaks because otherwise it was ploting now random colors in the legend :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to use colors from a column in your dataset I would go for `scale_color_identity`. However, if you want a legend and want to assign labels I would suggest to map a dataframe column on the `color` aes, i.e. as far as I get it you want to color by `processing.level`. Then use named vectors to assign your labels and colors via `scale_color_manual`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

pal_color <- unique(consumption_supplychain$col)
names(pal_color) <- unique(consumption_supplychain$processing.level)

labels_color <- c(
  "Domestically produced hides",
  "Trade in raw hides",
  "Trade in tanned hides",
  "Trade in leather",
  "Trade in consumer goods"
)
names(labels_color) <- 1:5

pal_color
#>         1         2         3         4         5 
#> "#073b4c" "#118ab2" "#06d6a0" "#ffd166" "#ef476f"
labels_color
#>                             1                             2 
#> "Domestically produced hides"          "Trade in raw hides" 
#>                             3                             4 
#>       "Trade in tanned hides"            "Trade in leather" 
#>                             5 
#>     "Trade in consumer goods"

consumption_supplychain %>%
  mutate(
    xval = as.numeric(factor(Country)) +
      scales::rescale(processing.level, to = c(-0.05, 0.05))
  ) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_segment(
    aes(
      x = xval, xend = xval, y = y, yend = yend,
      color = factor(processing.level)
    ),
    linejoin = "bevel",
    lineend = "butt",
    linewidth = 1.5,
    arrow = arrow(angle = 55, length = unit(1.5, "mm"))
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = pal_color,
    labels = labels_color,
    name = NULL
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous("",
    breaks = 1:5,
    labels = c("Brazil", "China", "Eropean Union", "India", "USA")
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::label_number(scale = 1 / 1000000)
  ) +
  ylab("Million tonnes per year")
```

[image]

```
consumption_supplychain <- structure(list(Country = c(
  "BRA", "BRA", "BRA", "BRA", "BRA",
  "CHN", "CHN", "CHN", "CHN", "CHN"
), processing.level = c(
  1L,
  2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L
), yend = c(
  957800, 959258,
  538306, 301212, 276294, 1446265, 2234591, 2843813, 2930715, 1309941
), y = c(
  0, 957800, 959258, 538306, 301212, 0, 1446265, 2234591,
  2843813, 2930715
), col = c(
  "#073b4c", "#118ab2", "#06d6a0", "#ffd166",
  "#ef476f", "#073b4c", "#118ab2", "#06d6a0", "#ffd166", "#ef476f"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
  "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"
))
```